# Looping through a model to check for propery that is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a model Auto in MVC application that has properties such as

```
public string Id { get; set; }
public bool IsOOS{ get; set; }
public string Make { get; set; }
public string Model { get; set; }
[XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
public DateTime? RegisteredDate { get; set; }
```

and a class that has this ...

```
var a = new Auto(){
Id = someIDcomingfromServer,
IsOOS = someOOScomingFromServer,
... 
}
```

what I want to be able to do is... to loop through those and see if any of the properties are now null.

how can I loop through and see if any of those properties (Id, IsOOS etc) contain null?

Thanks

Comment: Are you wanting to check the _input_ (e.g. `someIDcomingfromServer`) or after the object has been created?  And what do you want to do if one of them _is_ null?  Set a default value?

Comment: `IsOOS` _can't_ be `null`.

Comment: After it is created. At this point if any of the properties contain null to capture that value and throw an exception.

Comment: If you want to loop dynamically through every property of an object, have a look at reflection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879197/using-reflection-read-properties-of-an-object-containing-array-of-another-object

Comment: @HaukurHaf I kinda new about this, and since it is an expensive process, is there any alternative?

Comment: I would weigh how often you need to do it before discounting reflection. If you're doing this a lot in a critically fast process, then another solution might be better. But check how slow reflection is before discounting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use reflection for this. Get all PropertyInfos from your instance and check their values.
Something like this:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo pinfo in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    object value = pinfo .GetValue(obj, null);
}
```

Beware, reflection is an expensive process.

Comment: I know and I should have mentioned about it, but is there any other options?

Comment: Yes, check one by one the values.

Answer (score 6):

Well you *could* use reflection to get a collection of all properties and check each for null, but why not just be explicit?

```
if (Id == null || Make == null || Model == null || RegisteredDate == null)
```

It's shorter, easier to understand, doesn't have the performance overhead of reflection, and doesn't require *that* much maintenance.  There's not a "magic" function that will tell you if any property of a class is null.

I would be careful not to shorten development time at the expense of system performance.  A little extra time spent in development (even if it's tedious) can make a huge difference in system performance.

That said, a single Linq-query would be:

```
bool hasNull = 
    a.GetType()
     .GetProperties()
     .Any(prop => prop.GetValue(a, null) == null);
```

Comment: good one, but unfortunately this model contains hundreds of pieces.. not my code...

Answer (score 1):

You can serialize it and search the string for /> since the serializer outputs nulls as  and empties as .  This may catch some empty objects as well as null objects.  If you only want nulls, you'd need to set them as nullable and look for xsi:nil="true" in the attributes.

*I posted this solution because you wanted another option.  The recommendations from the others are the advised way to do it.

Comment: You are right, I couldn't find a better way ... I will go with others advice.